# Defining a symbolic function on a list of inputs [solved, but the reason is unclear]

Tags: functions, symbolic

The following MWE should give a symbolic function (is this the correct terminology?) `f`, defined on the entries of some list `list`. 
As a test, we also print the output of `f` of each "basis" element.

```
list = Table[i, {i, 1, 3}];

For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++,
  f[list[[j]]] := Symbol["c" <> ToString[j]];
  Print[f[j]];
];
```

The output is of course

```
c1
c2
c3
```

However, if we map `f` to `list`,

```
f /@ list
```

then the output is

```
{c4,c4,c4}
```

I don't expect this, and scoping doesn't help either. So my questions are:

- **Why is this happening?**
- **How can I resolve this problem?**

---

***EDIT:***

I found a solution: I simply changed that one line to

```
f[list[[j]]] := Evaluate[ Symbol["c" <> ToString[j]] ];
```

But I still want to know why it happened in the first place? Why is mathematica not resolving the variable in the for loop?

Comment: Look at `Definition@f` and `Definition@j`, that should answer your question. Also, instead of `…:=Evaluate[…]`, simply use `…=…`, which automatically evaluates the right hand side when evaluated.

Comment: What is lambda[j] in your code?

Comment: Oh you are right! <code>:=</code> is basically something like "delayed evaluation", right? Totally forgot that.

Comment: @AlexTrounev: It's f[j], I just forgot to rename it.

Comment: OK, see `list = Table[i, {i, 1, 3}];
f[j_] := Symbol["c" <> ToString[list[[j]]]];
For[j = 1, j <= 3, j++, Print[f[j]];];` out `c1 c2 c3`; `f /@ list` out `{c1, c2, c3}`

Comment: Really? That's not what I get. If I just copy your inputs, Alex, I will still get `{c4,c4,c4}` after `Map`. Weird

Comment: I have marked this question as *already has an answer* -- please see the banner inserted at the top.  The cause and solution are the same.  The right-hand-side of a ` := ` expression is *held*.  You can in this case merely use `Set` (shorthand `=`) instead: `f[list[[j]]] = Symbol["c" <> ToString[j]]` but also see the linked question for a better understanding.  Also reference [(633)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/633/121) for why `With` is useful there.